# Вывод части текста

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, я хотел сделать так, чтобы большой тест выводился не полностью, например есть текст:

> Рассказывая о различных техниках сайтостроения, было бы нелепо не рассказать о некоторых способах создания модальных окон. О назначении, полезности и косяках использования всплывающих модальных окон мы расписывать не будем. Разберем один из многочисленных методов создания таких окошек.

Должно выводится только:

> Рассказывая о различных техниках сайтостроения, было бы нелепо не рассказать о некоторых способах создания модальных окон. О назначении....

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что и где вы делаете.. Подробнее немного можно?

Answer (score 2):

Обрезать текст можно с помощью функции [substr](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.substr.php), например:

```
$test = substr($text,0,200);
$test = $test . "...";
echo $test;
```

в $text ваш текст который нужно обрезать.

Comment: для русских символ, та и для  юникода лучше использовать mb_substr

Answer (score 2):

Создаем поле и называем его textpole

```
 <?php
    $text = $_POST['textpole'];
    $textupd = substr($text,0,500); //тут вместо 500 то количество которое хотите чтоб выводилось.
    $textupd2 = $textupd."...";
    echo $textupd2;
    ?>
Если что-то не так извините я только учусь.
Вот вообще четкое решение на js помоему, обрезает по словам.

  function maxsite_str_word($text, $counttext = 10, $sep = ' ') //Вместо 10 поставь нужное количество слов
{
    $words = split($sep, $text);
    if ( count($words) > $counttext )
        $text = join($sep, array_slice($words, 0, $counttext));
    return $text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

echo 'Рассказывая о различных техниках сайтостроения, было бы нелепо не рассказать о некоторых способах создания модальных окон. О назначении....';

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете обрезать текст функцией substr

```
// Это исходная строка
$text = "Это какой-то длинный текст"

// Это первые ее 10 символов
echo substr($text, 0, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы все шутите да? Substr? Если сайт на utf-8, то русские буквы некорректно обрабатываются этой функцией, потому что занимают два байта, да что тут говорить.
Вот хороший пример http://profiphp.ru/useful/15-trimming_string.html

Answer (score 0):

Если сайт на UTF-8, то в mb_substr надо прописать кодировку:

```
mb_substr($text, 0, [кол-во символов], 'UTF-8')
```

Answer (score 0):

На клиенте такие вещи надо делать, по размеру блока.

Вот, например, [jQuery.dotdotdot](http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/).